# add role on WordPress in PHP on a second database

Tags: php, database, sql

I have a site A (a store) where once the purchase is made the new user has to register in site B (a members area).

To do this I connected the second database and also managed to pass the various info with the following method:

```
$DB_MEMBERSHIP->insert( 'wpvm_users', array('user_login' => $user_login, 'user_pass' => $user_pass, 'user_nicename' => $user_nicename, 'user_email' => $order_billing_email, 'user_registered' => $user_registered, 'display_name' => $display_name) );
```

Now though, I'm wondering how it's possible to add the role. How can I do that?

I use the following code to insert the user meta:

```
$id_user = $DB_MEMBERSHIP->get_var("SELECT ID FROM `wpvm_users` WHERE user_email = '" . $order_billing_email . "'");
$DB_MEMBERSHIP->insert('wpvm_usermeta', array('user_id' => $id_user, 'meta_key' => 'first_name', 'meta_value' => $order_billing_first_name));
```

Comment: Doing this via direct SQL is the hardest method of doing it. Was there a reason you didn't use a multisite? Then you could trivially add the user to the other site with a function call. Other options include REST API and WP CLI interactions

Comment: I don't want to use a multisite because I don't want a platform that is too heavy. Consider that all the other products in the store don't have to link to my B site at all. Only one product, if purchased, has to send info to site B.

Comment: I already tried using CURL, but the request would get heavy and timeout closing the session and not completing it. Do you have any libraries that explain how to use REST API or CLI? I have used them very little

Comment: multisite doesn't make a site heavy, wp.com is a multisite install, with tens of millions+ of subsites and hundreds of millions of user accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve after several attempts using the following code:

```
// Insert the role
$role = array('gold_role' => 1);
$serialized_role = serialize($role);
$DB_MEMBERSHIP->insert('wpvm_usermeta', array('user_id' => $user_id, 'meta_key' => 'wpvm_capabilities', 'meta_value' => $serialized_role));
```

It works very well and doesn't slow down the shopping experience.